# how to deal with duplicated named parameters /:uuid/:uuid on an HTTP router

Tags: http, design-patterns, api-design

When creating an HTTP router, is common to see this pattern:

```
/get/:user         --> /get/username
/get/:book/:page/  --> /get/book/3
```

The handlers for the request can call a method the one will return the matching name, for example:

```
get(":user") and that return "username"
get(":book") and that return "book"
..
```

In most cases a key/value [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is used for storing this pairs, but what could be a best practice to deal with named parameters that have different values but share the same name, for example a hash or an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), example:

```
/get/:uuid/:uuid/  --> get/36146E6-D7EB-421C-9F7D-5F676A481A00/E122DA77-171E-4FAB-91CB-C724BF25B772
```

One "practice" I have found is to save the key and an array with the values in the order of appearance, something like:

```
:uuid = [uuid0, uuid1]
```

that way, the getting of the params can be consistent:

```
get(":uuid")  return array of UUIDS instead of only the first uuid
```

Probably a best practice could be to avoid using duplicated params names, and that could solve all this, but there are cases when the same regex/method is tight to the same named parameter and is desired to avoid duplication code just with a different name, I mean something like

```
:uuid1 = uuidgen()
:uuid2 = uuidgen()
```

So would like to know what could be a best approach for dealing with this cases.

Comment: '/get/:uuid/:uuid/'  what does this do? what is the relationship between first uuid and second uuid?

Comment: is just an example, the uuid are uniques but relation between could be more related to the app, probably something like this,  /books/:uuid/page/:uuid/

Comment: is this for the purpose of /books/:book_id/page/:pageNo ?? I can't understand why do you want to introduce the same variable here?

Comment: like I said is only an example, and the idea is that if book_id is an UUID, and :pageNO is also an UUID you could use the same ``regex``, you could duplicate the ``regex`` so that ``book_id`` and ``pageno`` do the same thing but the main question is how to deal in cases where you have the same named param.

Comment: So basically u want the same variable name, but different values in path config? Is that what you are telling? I am sorry I can't understand since this is a strange one :)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a strange case, and normally you want to avoid it, but to handle this I came with the idea off creating an array, with the contents of the variables, so for this strange cases you still using the ``get(":uuid")`` and  get an array the one is up to the developer to handle, but basically wanted what other patters could be used to handle this.